# instanceof Feature can not be recognized

Tags: javascript, if-statement, openlayers

I have one open layer feature as shown here:

```
var ROLE = new Feature();
ROLE: _ol_Feature_ {pendingRemovals_: {…}, dispatching_: {…}, listeners_: {…}, revision_: 0, ol_uid: 22555, …}
```

When I execute this piece of code for this feature, it returns me false.

```
if(ROLE instanceof Feature) //returns false
```

I can not see why condition is false.

Comment: Did you create `ROLE` by writing `new Feature()`?  It doesn't seem like it ... but for something to be an instance of a class it has to be created through that class.

Comment: @machineghost Yes I had exactly created it using new Feature ( ).

Comment: Was it the same `Feature`?  Because your debugging output suggests it was an `_ol_Feature_` ... and even if that's some sort of transpiling thing you could still have two different classes that are both called `Feature`.

Comment: @machineghost Yes it is same feature. Is there any method or way to convert _ol_Feature_ into Feature?

Comment: It depends: if `_ol_Feature` is just Babel or Webpack renaming `Feature` as part of its packaging of your code (or something like that), then you can't convert something to what it already was ... but if that was the case your `instanceof` wouldn't be `false` and you wouldn't have filed this question.  So it seems more likely that they are different, and in that case no, you can't make a `new Foo()` be an `instanceof Bar` (or a `new _ol_Feature_()` be an `instanceof Feature`).

Comment: @machineghost Yeah, make sense. thanks for explaination

Comment: Here's what I'd do if I were in your shoes.  Somewhere in your code you have `var ROLE = new Feature();` right?  Try adding `console.log(ROLE instanceof Feature)` immediately on the line after.  What I suspect you'll see is that it logs `true`, because it *is* an instance of *that* `Feature` class.  Now, add another line, `console.log(Feature)`, and do that both right after you make `ROLE`, and wherever else in your code you are doing `ROLE instanceof Feature`.  What I suspect you'll realize is that you have two different `Feature`s.  Good luck!

Comment: @machineghost Yes now I see at the time of creation, it gives me true for being instance of Feature, but later while encoding my data to Json, this ROLE is no more instance of featue. Meanwhile, there is 1 more problem while creating ROLE feature, in my debugging output I see it undefined and see other variables named as _ROLE working and holding newly created feature. And one more _ROLE2 variable also being undefined. What kind of behavior it shows.

Comment: "while encoding my data to Json" - You completely left this out of your question, but it's a critical detail!  When asking questions here, *please* strive to include all relevant code/details. When you "serialize" an object into JSON, it is *not* the same object: it's just a *representation* of that object.  In other words, `JSON.stringify(foo) instanceof Foo` will **never** be `true`, for *any* `foo`.

Comment: P.S. Any sort of "and there's one more problem" belongs in its own Stack Overflow question, so that each "Stack Overflow question" is only about one actual question.

Comment: @machineghost  thanks for your patience and clarification. it helped.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The way `instanceof` works in Javascript is that it checks an object's "prototype chain'.  You can read up online about Javascript's prototypal inheritance if you want, but the important part to understand is that for:

```
foo instanceof Foo
```

to be true, you have to have created `foo` from `Foo`, eg.:

```
const foo = new Foo();
```

However, it seems that your debugging output shows that your `ROLE` variable was created by instantiating an `_ol_Feature_` function, so it won't be an instance of `Feature`.